# Cannot find Grass7 folder in QGIS 2.18 content folder

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-2

I have freshly re-installed QGIS 2.18.28 in the prescribed order.
I was under the impression Grass7 in included in one of the install packages.
But when trying to point QGIS to the grass7 folder under "processing options" in QGIS, I cannot find that folder.
See screenshot attached.[image]